# Система регистрации по приглашениям

Tags: mysql, php, регистрация, sql

Привет всем!

Может кто-то подсказать как реализовать систему регистрации по инвайтам? Я представляю примерно так:

- В базе генерируются рандомные 5000 инвайтов.
- Пользователи при регистрации вводят логин, пароль,e-mail и инвайт.
- Подтверждают e-mail и тогда у них в личном кабенете появляется ещё 2 инвайта которые они могут дать друзьям.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать?

Создание регистрации и подтверждения e-mail'a я реализовать смогу, в вот всё, что связано с инвайтами...

Answer (score 2):

В таблице инвайтов можно хранить ещё id юзера, который получил инвайт, и id юзера, который по нему зарегистрировался.

- при регистрации проверяете, есть ли такой инвайт в таблице и не присвоен ли ему уже id зарегистрированного юзера. Если присвоен - инвайтом кто-то уже воспользовался, предлагаем пользователю ввести другой инвайт. Если не присвоен - регистрация успешна, присваиваем введенному инвайту id свежезарегистрированного юзера.
- при успешной регистрации добавляете в таблицу с инвайтами ещё два. Этим инвайтам присваиваете id получившего юзера.
- на странице профиля юзера с доступными ему инвайтами - выводите все инвайты, id получившего которые соответствует id юзера и у которых пустое поле зарегистрировавшегося юзера

Comment: Мне нужна помощь в реализации, а про базу я чуть-чуть по другому планировал. В таблице 2 колонки, инвайт и валидность(по дефолту там еденица) и при регистрации по инвайту в валидности ставится ноль.

Comment: А как вы собирались присваивать инвайты юзерам? Чтобы те видели доступные им инвайты.

Answer (score 2):

Я прокоментирую:

> В базе генерируются рандомные 5000 инвайтов.

зачем ? просто генерируйте инвайт когда нужно, если глобальное кол-во ограничено, храните счетчик или делайте count().

> Пользователи при регистрации вводят логин, пароль,e-mail и инвайт.

- во первых, если есть email то логин не нужен.
- во вторых пусть инвайт будет ссылкой, скажем http://example.com/register/44878dhjhdjh47
- ещё рассмотрите вопрос о генерации инвайтов на email, тогда email подтверждать не придется (в кабинете кнопка "выслать инвайт" пользователь указывает email друга, другу приходит приглашение)
- может быть стоит сделать ttl для приглашений - чтобы можно было возвращать старые приглашения, для непринятых (30 дней скажем действует)

Таблица с приглашениями должна выглядеть примерно так:

```
id varchar (64) primary,issuer_id int,email varchar(255) unique, issued_date, used shorint default 0;
```

когда человек приходит по ссылке c id, вы делаете следующее - проверяете поле used у соответствующего приглашения (select from invites where id=':id' and used=0), спрашиваете подтверждение TOS, пароль, имя/ник, заводите пользователя и выставляете used в 1.

Можно ещё для злостных троллей аннулировать их приглашения, удалять старые приглашения и пр.

Ах да - проверить сколько пользователь может выписать приглашений можно так-же выборкой из базы.

реализация всего этого очень похожа на реализацию подтверждения емайла, если какие-то конкретные вопросы, попробуйте написать код и покажите те части, которые вызывают затруднения.

Comment: насчёт мэйла вместо логина - хорошая идея
инвайт в виде ссылке не нужен,так как не имеет смысла
высылать инвайты на мэйл можно,но не нужно )
а генирироват ьв базе 5000 ивайтов для огранечения кол-ва пользователей.то есть хочу создать сайт на котором будет всего 5000 пользователей,и инвайты будут братся из базы,тоесть я раскидываю друзьям инвайты,они регаются подтверждают мэйл,и у них в кабинете появляется ещё по 2 инвайта,а мои инвайты становятся не валидными то есть в базе в столбец выставляется 0,тогда они уже раздают по 2 своих инвайта и т.д

Comment: я и говорю, зачем вам готовить приглашения заранее, когда можно создать их по запросу приглашающего. 

не важно будут ли приглашения высланы на почту, важно, что перейти по ссылке инвайта намного проще, чем вбивать его ручками.

Comment: @eicto //(offtopic) проще то оно проще, но.. пропадёт вся интрига! Ввод инвайта на каком-нибудь элитарном сайте, дрожащими от волнения руками, затаив дыхание - это ведь целый ритуал :D//

Comment: по ссылке понятно проще перейти,но мне это не нужно )

Comment: Мыло конечно хорошо, но его могут угнать.

Comment: всё могут угнать, даже тело.

Answer (score 1):

Введите 2 столбца у пользователя, т.е. 2 пустых слота, к примеру записывать туда id приглашенных. А инвайт можешь сделать какой нить **закодированный ID приглашающего** (не хэш, чтобы можно было понять кто кодировал), или **хэш ID приглашающего** (тогда его надо будет заносить в базу). Приглашенный вводит заветный инвайт, если слот у приглашающего свободен, записываем туда ID нового пользователя (Если в базе пользователей <5000, иначе естественно не давать зарегестрироваться). *p.s. Данные извращения я привел только ради поставленной цели, т.е. поставленные цели я считаю дикими :)*

> Ввод инвайта, дрожащими от волнения руками, затаив дыхание - это ведь целый ритуал :D

какая-то секта по вводу инвайта. Складывается впечатление, что вся цель сайта - ввод инвайта )))